# Diplay name on highstock column

Tags: postgresql, dns, highcharts

I have to draw a chart showing the DNS query over time on a internal network, for that I use Highstock as you can see bellow :

[image: DNS hits graph]

**What I need is to displaying the name of DNS on the tooltip**, the DNS name and hits are stored into database.

Code for completeness:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(function () {
new Highcharts.StockChart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'dns_chart',
        type: 'column',
    },

    title: {
        text: 'DNS Hits by Sentinel Controller'
    },

    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [
            {type: 'hour',count: 1,text: '1h'},
            {type: 'day',count: 1,text: '1d'},
                            {type: 'day',count: 3,text: '3d'},
                            {type: 'day',count: 7,text: '1w'},
                            {type: 'day',count: 14,text: '2w'},
                            {type: 'month',count: 1,text: '1m'},
                            {type: 'year',count: 1,text: '1y'},
                            {type: 'all',text: 'all'}
        ],
        selected : 7
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {text: 'Hits'}
    },

    xAxis: {
        title: { text: 'Domain name'}
    },

    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: [true,true],
        shared : true,
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y} hits</b>'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },

    series: [{
        name : 'DNS hits',
        dataGrouping : {
            enabled : false
        },
        data: ([
            <% @HighStock_result.each{ |row| %>
            [Date.UTC(<%=row['qt']%>),<%=row['hits']%>],
            <%}%>
        ]),
        dataGrouping: {
                approximation: "sum",
                enabled: true,
                forced: true,
                units: [['millisecond',[500]]],
        }
    }]
});

});
</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this information in the series object like:

```
series:[{
   name: 'DNS Info',
   dnsName: 'DNS name',
   data:[1,2,3]
}]
```

then in the tooltip formatter (`this.series.options.dnsName`) or pointFormat add `series.options.dnsName`